# How to detect no touches in screen JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have simple HTML page is showed on mobile devices. How to detect no changes/touches and execute function after time (leave user from page)?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Do your [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/6634591), [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

Comment: It is simple, how to explain more. I need to detect no changes on the page. When user sleeps during some time, then do something

Comment: What should happen when the user does nothing and what have you tried to make this work?

Comment: @OPV Check my answer below if it helps you

Comment: When user do nothing he will be redirected to another page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if user is not doing anything from sometime.

```js
            var t;
            window.onload = resetTimer;
            

            document.onmousemove = resetTimer;
            document.onkeypress = resetTimer;
        
            function doSomething() {
                alert("User did nothing for 3 seconds")
            }
        
            function resetTimer() {
                clearTimeout(t);
                t = setTimeout(doSomething, 3000)
                // 1000 ms= 1 sec
            }
```

Comment: Probably not, no. This event is fired when the user leaves the page, not when they don't do anything

Comment: Absolutely yes. You're right. But the above answer is referring to his this sentence 'execute function after time (leave user from page)'. I assume that he's running some function to check if the user is idle for a time :)

Comment: Okay, I understood that part as an action to take when the user doesn't do anything. User doesn't do anything -> leave user from page

Comment: Edited my answer. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, I will explore this code

Comment: Np. Place in a snippet now